# Normalization transformation of a probability density

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, density-function

Let $(X,Y,Z)$ be distributed according to the pdf $p(x,y,z)$. What would be the pdf $q(x,y,z)$ of the multivariate random variable $(X',Y',Z') = (X,Y,Z)/\sqrt{X^2+Y^2+Z^2}$? The method that I have studied in school with the Jacobian and the inverse of the transformation doesn't seem to apply to this case (the function doesn't have a well-defined inverse since we lose the length information). Is there any generic method to deal with cases like this?

I would also appreciate any recommendation for a good reference (preferably) for engineers that deals with problems like this too, and not only with the standard problems studied in an engineering degree not focused on mathematics.

Comment: Although convenient change of variables sometimes depends on the actual form of the pdf of $(X,Y,Z)$, you can try transforming to spherical coordinates $(x,y,z)\to(r,\theta,\phi)$ such that $x=r\cos\theta,\,y=r\sin\theta\cos\phi,\,z=r\sin\theta\sin\phi$. Then you are looking for the pdf of $(\cos\theta,\sin\theta\cos\phi,\sin\theta\sin\phi)$, which is to be found from the pdf of $(r,\theta,\phi)$.

Comment: Granted I may be able to do that, but how does that help me to compute the pdf? The transformation is still non-invertible meaning I still cannot use the method with the jacobian (even if the jacobian is easy to compute in both cases).

Comment: Why non-invertible? The transformation is invertible and the jacobian is known.

Comment: So how would you invert it? You lose the length information. Even something as simple as $x' = x /\sqrt(x^2 + y^2), y' = y / \sqrt(x^2 + y^2)$ is still not invertible, since it is a mapping from all possible points onto the unit circle. Needless to say it is not injective.

Comment: The polar transformation is invertible.

Comment: Yes, but it does not help with the original not being. I do not see how going to spherical coordinates helps me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a reference which solves this issue: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Probability/Transformation_of_Probability_Densities